# Overwrite fields using sort in jcl

Tags: sorting, mainframe

I have two files, F1 has 4 fields and file 2 has 14 fields.

I want to overwrite the file 2 in certain position with the values from file 1. As there are no common keys between 2 files, I didn't use join key. Over lay also didn't work and finally I'm getting only the 4 fields which were in F1 in the 0/p instead of 14 fields and in which 4 field value must be from F1.

Comment: [DFSORT Application Programming Guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc236878/$file/icea100_v2r3.pdf)

Comment: Please edit your question and show the sort statements you tried, as well as sample data for the two files. Also, remove the `JCL` tag, since it does not apply to your question.

Comment: F1: axedv 186432899 as23456 ds35678

Comment: If there are no common keys how are you expecting this merge to work? Are you expecting, for example, to match on record number?